# Make the screen scroll down ~2cm when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress website and there is a specific box where I can:

> Trigger this JS code each time user answers something (Don't add any `<script>...</script>` tags here, just put your JS code.)

This prefers to a plugin. This is a multiple answer quiz. But after they answer, I would like the screen to scroll just a bit (NEXT button is just off screen which I'd love for them not to scroll on their own for obvious reasons)

Image of what it looks like:

[image]

Is this something that can be done by just inserting it in the box specified?

I'm a box of hammers when it comes to coding but does [this](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2) website have what I'm looking for?

I tried to paste it in the box but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Most web browsers support the [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method, which provides more consistent behavior than the (rather old) jQuery code you're looking at.

Using this method is pretty straightforward. The only difficult part will be identifying the element corresponding to the next question; how this works will depend on the specific site/plugin you're working with.